# Download DIV Content as image with the Google QR Code API

Tags: javascript, php, canvas

When downloading the image the Google QR Code API is blank. When I use different image instead of the Google QR Code API it is included.

```
'''

<!-- div to be generated -->
<div id="qrid">
    <h1>Sample ID</h1>
    <img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&choe=UTF-8">
</div>
<button onclick="downloadDiv('qrid')">Print as Image</button>


<!-- import jquery and html2canvas -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadDiv(divid) {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById(divid)).then(function (canvas) { 
            $("#previewImg").append(canvas);
            var anchorTag = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(anchorTag);
            // document.getElementById(divid+"2").appendChild(canvas);
            anchorTag.download = "Visitor_"+divid+".png";
            anchorTag.href = canvas.toDataURL();
            anchorTag.target = '_blank';
            anchorTag.click();
        });
    }
</script>
'''
```

Comment: This work for me: `{ allowTaint: false, useCORS: true }`

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the options **allowTain** As follow and make sur that the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header is enable for your site

```
 function downloadDiv(divid) {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById(divid), {allowTaint : true}).then(function (canvas) { 
            $("#previewImg").append(canvas);
            var anchorTag = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(anchorTag);
            // document.getElementById(divid+"2").appendChild(canvas);
            anchorTag.download = "Visitor_"+divid+".png";
            anchorTag.href = canvas.toDataURL();
            anchorTag.target = '_blank';
            anchorTag.click();
        });
    }
```